# Elastic Search-OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO:os::commit_memory(0x00000006c9600000,4137680896,0) failed;error='Not enough space'(errno=12

Tags: java, elasticsearch, jvm, ubuntu-18.04

I had installed Elastic search on my ubuntu 18.04 and configured the .yml file following the steps below:

````
wget -qO - https://artifacts.elastic.co/GPG-KEY-elasticsearch | sudo apt-key add -
sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https

echo "deb https://artifacts.elastic.co/packages/7.x/apt stable main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/elastic-7.x.list```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install elasticsearch

sudo /bin/systemctl daemon-reload
sudo /bin/systemctl enable elasticsearch.service
sudo /bin/systemctl start elasticsearch.service
````

But, it is not starting and prompts: **Job for elasticsearch.service failed because the control process exited with error code.**

Below is the status:

```
elasticsearch.service - Elasticsearch
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/elasticsearch.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2021-02-11 19:25:03 IST; 17min ago
     Docs: https://www.elastic.co
  Process: 29519 ExecStart=/usr/share/elasticsearch/bin/systemd-entrypoint -p ${PID_DIR}/elasticsearch.pid --quiet (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 29519 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
Feb 11 19:25:03 naveensakthivel-HP systemd-entrypoint[29519]: error:
Feb 11 19:25:03 naveensakthivel-HP systemd-entrypoint[29519]: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: INFO: os::commit_memory(0x00000006c9600000, 4137680896, 0) failed; error='Not enough space' (errno=12)
Feb 11 19:25:03 naveensakthivel-HP systemd-entrypoint[29519]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOption.flagsFinal(JvmOption.java:119)
Feb 11 19:25:03 naveensakthivel-HP systemd-entrypoint[29519]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOption.findFinalOptions(JvmOption.java:81)
Feb 11 19:25:03 naveensakthivel-HP systemd-entrypoint[29519]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmErgonomics.choose(JvmErgonomics.java:38)
Feb 11 19:25:03 naveensakthivel-HP systemd-entrypoint[29519]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.jvmOptions(JvmOptionsParser.java:135)
Feb 11 19:25:03 naveensakthivel-HP systemd-entrypoint[29519]:         at org.elasticsearch.tools.launchers.JvmOptionsParser.main(JvmOptionsParser.java:86)
Feb 11 19:25:03 naveensakthivel-HP systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 11 19:25:03 naveensakthivel-HP systemd[1]: elasticsearch.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 11 19:25:03 naveensakthivel-HP systemd[1]: Failed to start Elasticsearch.
```

Thanks.

Comment: what is the RAM of your machine?

Comment: I have a RAM of 8 GB.

Answer (score 0):

I am a Windows environment. The main reason for this is the memory problem. You can close several applications or add memory modules. Linux can add virtual space

Answer (score -1):

Looks like there is no enough RAM available on your machine, due to which ES process is existing and same is mentioned as `Not enough space`. can you try increasing the RAM of your machine.